# (Speed Calculate) How Make Simple way?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, multiprocessing

I have huge dataframe,, hundred thousand row and column．

My data like this:

```
df

MAC T_1 X_1 Y_1 T_2 X_2 Y_2 T_3 X_3 Y_3 T_4 X_4 Y_4 T_5 X_5 Y_5 T_6 X_6 Y_6 T_7 X_7 Y_7
ID1 1   1   1   1   1   1   2   1   2   3   1   3   3   1   3   4   1   4   5   1   5
ID2 6   2   5   6   2   5   7   3   5   7   3   5   8   4   5   9   5   5   10  5   4
ID3 1   1   1   2   1   2   3   1   3   3   1   3   4   1   4   5   1   5   6   2   5
```

I want to calculate the speed using this equation:

[image]

I used code:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
def v_2(i):
     return (df.ix[x,(5+3*(i-1))]-df.ix[x,(2+3*(i-1))])**2 + (df.ix[x,(6+3*(i-1))]-df.ix[x,(3+3*(i-1))])**2

def v(i):
    if (df.ix[x,(4+3*(i-1))]-df.ix[x,(1+3*(i-1))]) ==0:
        return 0
    else:
        if (df.ix[x,(4+3*(i-1))]-df.ix[x,(1+3*(i-1))]) <0:
            return 0
        else:
            return math.sqrt(v_2(i)) / (df.ix[x,(4+3*(i-1))]-df.ix[x,(1+3*(i-1))]) 

for i in range(1,int((len(df.columns)-1)/3)):
v_result = list()
for x in range(len(df.index)):
    v_2(i)
    v(i)
    v_result.append(v(i))
df_result[i]=v_result
```

my expected result:

```
MAC V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6
ID1 0   1   1   0   1   1
ID2 0   1   0   1   1   1
ID3 1   1   0   1   1   1
```

but this code takes huge time,
would you mind to give another idea more simple and fast process or using multiprocessing module.
thank you

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve] with sample data, your expected output and words explaining the logic you are trying to implement? It seems like those operations can be done without the loop and with vectorized functions.

Comment: Side note. `.ix` accessor has been deprecated in favour of `.loc` / `.iloc`.

Comment: Thank you for your suggest. Iam newbie in python, in my case no problem with this code but it takes 4 days processing, I need more simple to make short time. I try separate between “def” and “for loop”, In for loop” takes more time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The calculation can be sped up quite a bit through reshaping the data first, so that efficient pandas methods can be used. If that is not fast enough, you can then go down to the numpy array and apply the functions there.

first reshape the data from the *wide* format to a *long* format so that there are only 3 columns, `T, X, Y`. The column suffixes, i.e. `_1`, `_2`, etc are split out into a new index.

```
df = df.set_index('MAC')
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(zip(*df.columns.str.split('_')))
df = df.stack()
```

this produces the following data frame:

```
        T  X  Y
MAC
ID1 1   1  1  1
    2   1  1  1
    3   2  1  2
    4   3  1  3
    5   3  1  3
    6   4  1  4
    7   5  1  5
ID2 1   6  2  5
    2   6  2  5
    3   7  3  5
    4   7  3  5
    5   8  4  5
    6   9  5  5
    7  10  5  4
ID3 1   1  1  1
    2   2  1  2
    3   3  1  3
    4   3  1  3
    5   4  1  4
    6   5  1  5
    7   6  2  5
```

Next calculate the `del_X^2`, `del_Y^2` & `del_t` (*I hope the usage of prefix `del` is unambiguous*). This is easier done using these two utility functions to avoid repetition.

```
def f(x):
    return x.shift(-1) - x

def f2(x):
    return f(x)**2
```

*update: description of functions*

> The first function calculates `F(W,n) = W(n+1) - W(n)`, for all `n`, where `n` is the index of the array W. The second function squares its argument. These functions are composed to calculate the distance squared. See the documentation for [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) for more information & examples.

using lower-case column names for the `del` prefix above and the suffix `2` to mean squared:

```
df['x2'] = df.groupby(level=0).X.transform(f2)
df['y2'] = df.groupby(level=0).Y.transform(f2)
df['t'] = df.groupby(level=0).Y.transform(f)
df['v'] = np.sqrt(df.x2 + df.y2) / df.t

df.v.unstack(0)
```

produces the following which is similar to your output, but transposed.

```
MAC  ID1  ID2  ID3
1    NaN  NaN  1.0
2    1.0  1.0  1.0
3    1.0  NaN  NaN
4    NaN  1.0  1.0
5    1.0  1.0  1.0
6    1.0  1.0  1.0
7    NaN  NaN  NaN
```

you can filter out the last row (where the computed columns `t`, `x2` & `y2` are null), fill the `np.nan` in v with with 0, transpose, rename the columns & reset index to get at your desired result.

```
result = df[pd.notnull(df.t)].v.unstack(0).fillna(0).T
result.columns = ['V'+x for x in result.columns]
result.reset_index()
# outputs:

   MAC   V1   V2   V3   V4   V5   V6
0  ID1  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0
1  ID2  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  ID3  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: this is good way. but I get another value from this procedure,, many negatif value data I got. would you mind to explain to me about your `def`? iam sorry Iam newbie in python,,

Comment: @Arief, see updated answer for description of functions.

Comment: @Arief, I don't see how you would get negative speed values, unless the T(n+1) < T(n) for some n. Also, my implementation is a fairly straightforward tranfer of your equation. It isn't possible to say why you get different values unless you share a bigger dataset. Maybe there is some other characteristic in your dataset not represented in the sample you shared. On the sample, my code produces your expected output. Can you put a bigger sample in [https://pastebin.com/](https://pastebin.com/), expected output  & actual output.

Comment: I will prepare big sample,, so I can understand where the problem is... thank you @Haleemur Ali

Comment: is it possible if the result get negative value so it must be 0 value?

Comment: this is the data (https://pastebin.com/j3GNpKdx)  and for the result  (https://pastebin.com/AvbXBGYy) thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use Apache Spark if you want a real speed.
You can do that by passing your function to Spark as described here in this documentation:

[Passing function to Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.1.1/programming-guide.html#passing-functions-to-spark)